# Is there way to add default query to mongo repository?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongorepository

Say, we have a class named person

```
public class Person{ 
   private String name;
   private boolean active; 
}
```

When I call `personRepository.findByName("John Doe")` the result should be the objects with the name John Doe and active is `True`. Meanwhile, when  `personRepository.findByNameAndActive("John Doe", false)`, it should return the result of all the objects with John Doe and active = false

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, default *MongoRepository* methods do not support **OR** or **AND** clauses.

[Supported keywords for query methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUoDe.png)

But you can use a **@Query** annotation to define what should be done by this method:

```java
@Query("{ 'name' : ?0, 'active' : true }")
Person findByName(String name);

@Query("{ 'name' : ?0, 'active' : ?1 }")
Person findByNameAndActive(String name, boolean active);
```